How does Google Scholar handle pre-print citations?
Sometimes a paper appears as a pre-print first, and then in a peer-reviewed form, possibly with more authors. And people might cite one or the other, and sometimes both.
Google Scholar can probably see that the papers are still similar. How does it handle the citations though? Are they completely independent? Or does citing one paper count towards the citation numbers of the other paper?

Google Scholar is fairly decent at collating different versions of the same manuscript (see here for an example from my own publication list). How it does that exactly I am not sure, probably based on title. It's definitely smart enough to see beyond simple cosmetic changes or layout differences.
Citations for either of the papers will then count towards the "master" manuscript. It does not matter for your citation count if people cite the preprint or the final paper (although of course the latter is the proper way to do it, and other people - most importantly reviewers or journal copy editors - are likely to insist on it).

This behaviour seems mostly true, except in the case the pre-print and the published version have different name (but then, I suppose you could argue the citation are different)

@JackRed Suggests that my suspicion that GS really just merges based on title is correct. Probably too noisy to do it otherwise.
